# How can I be notified that a repaint occurred in the child tree?

Tags: flutter

I need to take a snapshot of a widget (to generate an `ui.Image`) every time the widget or its children is repaint.

To take the snapshot of a widget I use a `RepaintBoundary` and it generate correctly the image with a `_captureImage` method.

How can I be notified that a repaint occurred in the child tree to call `_captureImage` only when it is needed (that is every time the visual representation of the child change)?

Here is a simplified version of my current widget.

```dart
class AutoSnapshotWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AutoSnapshotWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final void Function(ui.Image) onChange;

  @override
  State<AutoSnapshotWidget> createState() => _AutoSnapshotWidgetState();
}

class _AutoSnapshotWidgetState extends State<AutoSnapshotWidget> {
  final _key = GlobalKey();

  // *****************************************************************
  // How to make this function called every time the child is repaint?
  // *****************************************************************  
  void _captureImage() async {
    final buildContext = _key.currentContext! as SingleChildRenderObjectElement;
    final boundary = buildContext.findRenderObject()! as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    final image = await boundary.toImage();
    widget.onChange(image);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: _key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By repaint/change you mean every time the widget gets rebuilt or every time the actual visual representation changes? 
Rebuilt i suppose can happen a lot of time but it doesn't necessary means that the visual representation of the widget has changed from the previous build

Comment: Good question. Ideally I would like to be notified only when the visual representation changes but being notified on child rebuild could be a first step.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like, you can take a snapshot every time your widget is done rebuilding. Make use of `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` to do that by editing your `build` method like so:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _captureImage());
    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: _key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's what I used but it seems quite inefficient to generate an image at every frame. That's why I was looking for a way to be notified when a change occurs.

Comment: Ideally, you'd only change the state of your widget when you want the visual representation of it to change, so this method should work. You might want to reinspect your code structure if you have cases where you're rebuilding the widget but there are no visual changes. As an alternative, you can setState with a manual flag (isNewVisualState or something), and call _captureImage in addPostFrameCallback only if(isNewVisualState)

Comment: Actually I have no control on the child widget and I don't have any clue about when it gets rebuilt. So with you proposal the image is only generated the first time AutoSnapshotWidget is built.

Comment: Perhaps try out didChangeDependencies and see if that helps your case?